# I am trying to use fread and fwrite to make a copy function but I keep getting strange output depending on the buffer size

Tags: c++, copy, buffer, fwrite, fread

I am trying to write a copy function which takes in three arguments when run in the command line. The program is run using the name of the program followed by the user specified buffer size and then the name of the input file and the name of the output file.

E.g. >>copyf 1024 input.txt output.txt which are stored in argv[0] to argv[3] respectively.

When I run the code with a buffer size of 1024 I get something like this:

> This is the beginning of the test file and I want to see how far it makes it in to the file before cutting stuff off.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ

When I run the code with a buffer size of 32 I get something like this:

> This is the beginning of the test file and I want to see how far it makes it in to the file before cutting stuff off.tting stuff

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    int end = 0;
    char buffer[65536];
    //Error checking
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        end = 1;
        printf("Error-Insufficient Arguments (%d/4)\n", argc);


    }
    FILE*fp, *outFile;
    fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    outFile = fopen(argv[3], "a");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        end = 1;
        printf("Error-Input file is fake\n");
    }

    //No errors. Proceed with copy code
    int size = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("Buffer size is: %d Bytes\n\n",size);

    if (end == 0)
    {
        printf("No Errors Detected\n\n");
        while (!feof(fp))
        {

            fread(&buffer, size, 1, fp);

            fwrite(&buffer, size, 1, outFile);

            for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++)
            {
                buffer[i] = NULL;
            }
        }

    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(outFile);

    clock_t endTime = clock();
    float endTimeSec = endTime;
    printf("Runtime = %f\n\n", endTimeSec / 1000);
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated. I have a feeling the source of the problem is with my understanding of how fread and fwrite work in this context.

Comment: You need to check return values from `fread` and `fwrite`.

Comment: Is `buffer[1] = NULL` supposed to say `buffer[i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

1. You are doing very little error handling (and not where it actually matters)
2. You are opening the files for reading/writing text data instead of binary data, so line breaks (if any) in the file data will possibly get converted to a different format.  For a true copy, you don't want the data to change at all.
3. You are asking `fread()` to read 1 element that is `size` bytes in size.  If the input file size is not an even multiple of `size`, the last element will fail and be ignored.  To account for that, you need to ask `fread()` to read `size` elements that a are 1 byte in size.
4. You are ignoring the return value of `fread()`, which tells you how much bytes were actually read.  Don't write more than that number of bytes to the output file.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    FILE *fp, *outFile;
    char buffer[65536];
    int bufSize, numRead;

    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Error-Insufficient Arguments (%d/4)\n", argc);
        return 0;
    }

    bufSize = atoi(argv[1]);
    if ((bufSize < 1) || (bufSize > sizeof(buffer))
    {
        printf("Error-Invalid Buffer Size (%d)\n", bufSize);
        return 0;
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[2], "rb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error-Input file not opened\n");
        return 0;
    }

    outFile = fopen(argv[3], "wb");
    if (outFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error-Output file not created\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

    //No errors. Proceed with copy code
    printf("Buffer size is: %d Bytes\n\n", bufSize);

    do
    {
        numRead = fread(buffer, 1, bufSize, fp);
        if (numRead < 1)
        {
            if ((ferror(fp) != 0) && (feof(fp) == 0))
                printf("Error-Reading from Input file\n");
            break;
        }

        if (fwrite(buffer, numRead, 1, outFile) != 1)
        {
            printf("Error-Writing to Output file\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    while (1);

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(outFile);

    clock_t endTime = clock();
    float endTimeSec = endTime;
    printf("Runtime = %f\n\n", endTimeSec / 1000);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- You can't assume that `fread()` filled the buffer.
- Unless you use an element size of 1, `fread()` can't tell you about partial reads.
- You need to feed the actual read count into `fwrite()`.
- You need to loop.

Putting it all together:

```
while ((count = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, fin)) > 0)
{
    fwrite(buffer, 1, count, fout);
}
```

And zeroing the buffer before or afterwards is a waste of time.